# should bundle exec find a global gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, visual-studio-code, bundler

visual studio code launch configuration (not terrible important) tries to start rdebug-ide via

```
bundle exec rdebug-ide
```

This works only if I add the gems to the Gemfile.

Is bundle exec supposed to only find binaries included in the Gemfiles or should those installed globally, e.g. `gem install rdebug-ide`, also be accessible from bundle exec?

So this works:

```
> rdebug-ide
Using ruby-debug-base 0.2.2 ...
```

but this doesn't

```
> bundle exec rdebug-ide
Gem::Exception: can't find executable rdebug-ide for gem ruby-debug-ide. ruby-debug-ide is not currently included in the bundle, perhaps you meant to add it to your Gemfile?
```

and even this works!

```
> bundle exec ls
Gemfile app ...
```

Extra info: I'm using rbenv, perhaps that affects bundler behavior somehow

**UPDATE**

@tadman pointed out that bundle exec is altering the path. But as I would have expected it seems to be extending it, not removing anything

```
$ diff <(gem env) <(bundle exec gem env)
24a25
>      - /Users/eng/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/bin

$ which rdebug-ide
/Users/eng/.rbenv/shims/rdebug-ide

$ bundle exec rdebug-ide
bundler: failed to load command: rdebug-ide 
(/Users/eng/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/bin/rdebug-ide)
Gem::Exception: can't find executable rdebug-ide for gem ruby-debug-ide. ruby-debug-ide is not currently included in the bundle, perhaps you meant to add it to your Gemfile?
```

furthermore the path is in there:

```
 $ bundle exec gem env | grep $(dirname $(which rdebug-ide))
 - /Users/eng/.rbenv/shims
```

I'm tending to think that `rbenv` is somehow messing things up.

Answer (score 0):

`bundle exec` does a number of things, primarily changing the Gem environment, but most importantly it alters your search `PATH` for executables.

Many, like `ls` which exist outside of Ruby will still be present, but gem executables may be knocked out if not included in the `Gemfile`.

Check with:

```
bundle exec gem env
```

And compare with:

```
gem env
```

You'll see a number of changes in the "SHELL PATH" section.

Comment: thanks for the info. But this behaves as expected, bundle exec adds one path line (so the search path is broader not narrower). And yet the file is not found... which makes me think, that it is found but somehow not accepted... any idea?

Comment: If it's not in the `Gemfile` then it might skip it. Add it to your `Gemfile` if you want to use it with Bundler.